# SQL CTE Returns Not A Group By Expression Error

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a CTE to return the sum of all lines of an invoice, but I am receiving an error : "Not a Group By Expression". Not sure what is wrong? Thanks.

```
with getinvoices as
(
select 
             i.invoice_nbr
            ,i.invoice_type_id
            ,i.invoice_type_desc
            ,i.invoice_total_amount
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.invoice_nbr ORDER BY i.rowid) rn
            ,sum(i.line_amount) as "Sum Of Line Amount"
             FROM ods_dev.invoices i
             WHERE i.invoice_date>='7/1/2020' and i.invoice_date<'7/2/2020'
                  AND i.invoice_nbr IS NOT NULL
             Group By
                 i.invoice_nbr
                ,i.invoice_type_id
                ,i.invoice_type_desc
                ,i.invoice_total_amount
)
Select *
From getinvoices g
Where g.rn = 1
Order by g.invoice_nbr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.invoice_nbr ORDER BY i.rowid) rn
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

I'm not sure what you want to do.  Perhaps:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.invoice_nbr ORDER BY MIN(i.rowid)) as rn
```

Or perhaps you want to include `rowid` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Adding the rowid to the Group By resolved the error.